# How to have multiple ip on windows

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I need to set multiples IP's on a computer running windows 7, so my computer is in the networks 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x

I only have one network interface, and i know this can be easily done with linux creating an alias using the following cmd

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.11 up
```

So theres any way to do that in windows using the command line ? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with something like

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address
```

so:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address “Local Area Connection” 192.168.1.11 255.255.255.0
```

see http://www.howtogeek.com/51741/how-to-quickly-add-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-servers/